# How do I open a new tab in Mobile Safari?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

How do I open a new browser window? Right now I have Safari. I apparently need to get another browser for some complicated reason just to post a moving gif. As you can probably tell, I'm not great with computers and especially my iPhone 6 which at the moment is the only thing I have in use. It still baffles me though that this little problem should be so hard to solve, I've already asked two people and read a lot of instructions on the Internet that seem so vague. I just can't seem to wrap my head around how it's done and I would love to know how. Can someone give me a "dumbed down" set of instructions for this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at below screens. Two steps, two arrows. Press double square to open tabs and then **+** to open new tab.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new tab in Mobile Safari by tapping on the icon at the bottom right. If the icon bar at the bottom doesn't show up, tap on the top row (where the clock and the status indicators are) first.

There is a lot of good documentation on http://support.apple.com/ as well.